# An irresistible force meets an unmovable object?

Tags: aristotle

> An irresistible force meets an immoveable object

This is a paradoxical statement. And one - well, at least I - tried to make sense of it. After all, most sentences one meets have a sense to them. And to understand is to understand the sense. And this is a habit hard to lose. Though, it sometimes seems, a habit worth losing.

It's possible, though, for some-one educated in the art of sentences and philosophy to so construct a sentence that no sense can be made of it. And it seems that this is such a sentence.

Its root appears to be a certain sentence from Aristotle where he defines force. To paraphrase and to put in short:

> A force is that which meets moveable object

This works and is, in fact, at the root of Newton's second law of motion where he defines force. So as a philosophical concept, this definition is fruitful.

Yet, the paradoxical formulation above is the formulation which lingers in the mind. It stays. It takes root. It asks to be noticed and knocks against the mind asking to be made sense of, when in fact it is so constructed as not to make sense.

** Q. Can in fact some sense be made of it?**

Comment: For the physical aspect: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9eKc5kgPVrA

Comment: It seems a simple situation. There can be an immovable object and there can be an irresistible force, but there cannot be both because that would be a contradiction.  ,.

Comment: @PeterJ.Totally right. Nothing would be immovable if it encountered an irresistible  force; and no force would be irresistible if it encountered an immovable object. I don't know the origin of this much-cited scenario. I only use it figurately - when, for instance, a very pushy person meets an extremely stubborn one. But this is a matter of English usage, not philosophy !. Best - Geoff

Comment: @geoffrey Thomas: I think you're right. It's a statement which draws us into thinking because of its paradoxical wording. But the lesson to be learnt is that nothing more can be made of it. A pity, I thought that there might be more to it. Godel, for example, said he was inspired and led to his theory by the Cretan Liar paradox.

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah. Thanks for comment. Look at the matter this way : you thought there might be substance in the paradox but it looks likely that there isn't. In realising this, you've made progress. I look forward to your future questions. Best - Geoff

Comment: I mean isn't the obvious solution, "If there is an irresistible force, there are no immovable objects, and *vice versa*"? So that either description can only apply individually per world, but not both descriptions in any one world?

Answer (score 1):

In nature, there cannot be an irresistible force, nor an immovable object. Everything can be measured in terms of a finite level of force that can be applied by it or to it before some change takes place. In our language however, superlatives and concepts of the infinite exist and this sentence is an elegant example of why they're difficult concepts to reconcile with what little understanding we have of the universe.

Even black holes don't fit this sentence. They are irresistible forces in terms of gravity if you get close enough, but Hawking radiation proves they're not perfectly irresistible. Also, they are *not* immovable objects. They have a finite mass (it's only their density that can be described as infinite) which means they can be attracted to other massive objects and therefore can be moved. In theory, a small enough black hole could even orbit a star.

Perhaps a good place to start would be Plato's plane of truth. Plato postulated that there was a plane of existence where all idealised concepts could exist in their perfect forms. In such a plane, it's possible that an immovable object could exist, and possibly even an irresistible force. He believed though that these perfect forms could not exist in the natural plane, which at best was only capable of approximations of the perfect.

From a linguistic perspective however, I think the answer is simpler; just like in mathematics where it's possible to derive an equation from any set of numbers (integers, rationals, surds, etc.) for which the answer *must* lie outside that set, so is it possible to derive a sentence from a set of superlatives where the answer *must* lie outside the frame of reference for superlatives. The question is currently a nonsense because we can't see beyond superlatives into the next realm of concepts. It may one day be conceptually possible to reconcile this sentence, but in order to do so we would have to philosophically derive a plane of existence beyond Plato's plane of truth.

Answer (score 1):

The paradox can be punctured if you discriminate different senses of 'meet'.

If the two merely meet in the sense that there is and remains an infinitesimal distance between them, then nothing will happen. They will meet without impact. If as I expect this answer is objected to, then (a) I can point out that 'meet' is a vague term and (b) I can reasonably ask what other sense of 'meet' is involved. If the two 'impact' or 'causally interact', I'd like an analysis of these less than luminously clear notions.

If we don't slice 'meet' into fine shades of meaning, which I'm doing as a conceptual exercise, PeterJ's comment is spot on.

Answer (score 0):

This implies trying to provide a physical solution to an empirically (therefore, physically) impossible ideal. All such complication is not necessary. If you want to solve physically unreal problems (this is empirically unreal, cause it has never been observed), take into account that they are *not real*, so you can't apply physical rules to describe and solve them, only logic is applicable.

In final terms, the problem is logical. A simple contradiction like this abstracts the same problem:

**x>y ^ x<y**

That's the essence of your question. And for such case, traditional logic tells that this is impossible. Unless a different logical framework is used, with different assumptions, axioms and concepts, which is what you seem to look for.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, the concepts of an "irresistible force" and an "immovable object" are *each* alone a plausible axiom for an alternative universe governed by physical laws each defined as a mathematical statement. (Without imposing any condition on how much that universe need resemble our own.)

And even in the same universe: As long as they never meet, there might be no problem.

But yes, indeed, if they were to meet, there would be a contradiction. Although to fully elucidate the contradiction we should have to define just what the meaning of location in the universe is, and this issue turns out to be very subtle.

So, these potential axioms for a hypothetical physics *might* be able to coexist under certain conditions.

Answer (score -1):

It provides useful context for the recognition seemingly coherent sentences can turn out to have problematic premises.

There is the [omnipotence paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnipotence_paradox) of whether god can create an object he cannot lift. This points to how the categories are empty, there is no [natural kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_kind) of unstoppable forces or immovable objects. Stoppability of forces, and movability of objects are contextual, relational and by degree, not absolute qualities.

The only reasonable answer is, 'The unstoppable force stops, the immovable object moves', invalidating the categories, but making a nice symmetry in the process.

The same problem occurs with absolutising being a liar, with then saying 'This sentence is a lie'.

These kind of paradoxes proved pivotal for philosophy, like Russell's paradox, & to Godel's work. It helps us understand more about definitions and logic.

Answer (score -1):

Presumably, everybody understands the idea of an irresistible force and everyone understands the idea of an immoveable object. Taken "possible" to mean something like compatible with reality as far as we know, an irresistible force is a force that nothing could possibly resist. Likewise, an immoveable object is an object which not force could possibly move. Whether there is any such a thing as an irresistible force or an immoveable object is irrelevant here since the question is about the possible meaning of the sentence.

Thus, as far as I can tell, there is no difficulty in the basic meaning of the statement. The problem of course arise with the conjunction of these two ideas. If there is an irresistible force, there cannot be an immovable object, and vice versa. We can conceive of either one independently of the other, not of the two as possibly existing in the same reality.

Thus, the expression works like a logical contradiction even if it is not a formal logic expression. Essentially, the existence of an immovable object would falsify the existence of an irresistible force, and vice versa.

By definition, contradictions are false, and so  it is not possibly true that there would be both an irresistible force and an immovable object.

Language allows us to assert contradictions as if they could possibly be true. This is not a problem with logic. It is, perhaps, a problem with language, and then we can observe that we can also speak falsely, and that this may prove very useful, including for example to save our life. Thus, asserting a contradiction is only a particular case of speaking falsely, although in this case, it would be ridiculous since it would obvious to anyone that a contradiction cannot possibly be true.